# Print elements using dt class name selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a simple **scraper** for Sales Navigator in Linkedin and this is the [link](https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/company?companySize=E&geoIncluded=emea%3A0%2Ceurope%3A0&industryIncluded=6&keywords=AI&page=1&searchSessionId=zreYu57eQo%2BSZiFskdWJqg%3D%3D) I am trying to **scrape** . It has search results for specific filter options selected for account results.

The goal I am trying to achieve is to retrieve every company name among the search results. Upon inspecting the link elements carrying the company name (eg : Facile.it, AGT international), I see the following js script, showing the **dt class name**

```
    <dt class="result-lockup__name">
    <a id="ember208" href="/sales/company/2429831?_ntb=zreYu57eQo%2BSZiFskdWJqg%3D%3D" class="ember-view">  Facile.it

    </a>    </dt>
```

I basically want to retrieve those names and open the url represented in href.

It can be noted that all the company name links had the same dt class **result-lockup__name**. The following script is an attempt to collect the list of all company names displayed in the search result along with its elements.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    def scrape_accounts(url):

        url = "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/companycompanySize=E&geoIncluded=emea%3A0%2Ceurope%3A0&industryIncluded=6&keywords=AI&page=1&searchSessionId=zreYu57eQo%2BSZiFskdWJqg%3D%3D"
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
        #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        #driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        driver.get(url)

        search_results = []
        search_results = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result-lockup__name")
        print(search_results)

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        scrape_accounts("lol")
```

however, the result prints an empty list. I am trying to learn scraping different parts of web page and different elements,and thus I am not sure if I got this correct. What would be the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't get to the page that you're after, but I notice that you're importing beautiful soup but not using it.

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/companycompanySize=E&geoIncluded=emea%3A0%2Ceurope%3A0&industryIncluded=6&keywords=AI&page=1&searchSessionId=zreYu57eQo%2BSZiFskdWJqg%3D%3D"

def scrape_accounts(url = url):

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
    #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)

    html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    search_results = soup.select('dt.result-lockup__name a')
    for link in search_results:
        print(link.text.strip(), link['href'])
```

Comment: my apologies. I notice that I logged in using my id and password in that account.

Comment: I believe the first error lies at the fact that the browser session started doesn't login

Comment: I had issues with sign in as well, as posted in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128400/sign-in-to-sales-navigator-python-selenium

Comment: But the above does get you the company names and URLs?

Comment: I feel this line is missing before using the html parser - html = driver.page_source

Comment: ah yes, answer adjusted, apologies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189915/discussion-between-lakshmi-narayanan-and-rockhardracoon).

Comment: The above code always results only 10 instances, irrespective of the no.of searches. Is there anything to do with only accessing the inner html?

Comment: Let's do this in the chat you started?